# jQuery: Native HTML5 Drag and drop among tabs

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a web application with a tabpane. The tabs are draggable elements, which I am hoping to be able to drag between other tabs in its tabpane and into other tabpanes in other windows. While the tab visually appears to be dragging I am not getting any response from my events.

```
<li draggable="true">Tab</li>

...

$('.tabpane__tabs li').on('dragover', function(e) {
    alert('test'); // Does not trigger
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.tabpane__tabs li').on('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', $('.tabpane__panes > li').eq($(this).index()).html());
});

$('.tabpane__tabs li').on('drop', function(e) {
    alert('test'); // Does not trigger
});
```

Comment: Native HTML5 tabs?

Comment: I'm looking to do this with the HTML draggable tag, not jQuery UI or other draggable methods that would not work between windows.

Comment: It does trigger. Your selectors for the `li` might be wrong. Can you post more of your html?

Comment: Figured it out. Forgot because tabs are dynamically added elements they need to be accessed like this: `$(document).on('dragover', '.tabpane__tabs li', function(e) { ... });`